# Is there a way to do a "left outer join" like query in PromQL?

Tags: monitoring, prometheus, promql

I am trying to use two metrics (that share some labels, including one that I can use as an UUID) that should describe the same entities, in order to create alerts/dashboard that will alert me one an entity reports in one metric but not the other.

For example, for the following metrics:

```
item_purchases{name="item1", count="5"}
item_purchases{name="item2", count="7"}

item_stock{name="item1", in_stock="1"}
item_stock{name="item2", in_stock="0"}
item_stock{name="item3", in_stock="1"}
```

I use `item_stock` as my "source of truth", and I'm trying to write a query that will return:

```
item_stock{name="item3", ...} # I don't care about the other labels, just the name.
```

I already have a query that helps me filter on certain conditions (For example - if an item was purchased but is not in stock like "item2") that looks something like:

```
item_purchases{in_stock="1"} * on (name) group_left () (item_purchases)
```

but unfortunately it just drops all the records in `item_stock` that don't have a matching timeseries in `item_purchases`  - like "item3", which is actually the result I'm looking for.

Does anyone have any experience coding these type of queries? Are they even possible in PromQL or should I revert to some other solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible using [unless](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators) operator:

```
item_stock unless item_purchases
```

Results in a vector consisting of the elements of `item_stock` for which there are no elements in `item_purchases` with exactly matching label sets. All matching elements in both vectors are dropped.

Note that the metrics in question do not have '*exactly matching label sets*' (`name` is common but `count` and `in_stock` are not). In this case you can use `on` to set the list of labels to match:

```
item_stock unless on(name) item_purchases
```