# Prometheus queries: How to give a default label when it is missing?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I'm trying to graph the temperature of my servers with Prometheus's `hwmon` and Grafana.

Relevant for this are 2 time series that `prometheus-node-exporter` offers:

- `node_hwmon_temp_celsius` which has the actual temperatures; it has labels like:

  - `{chip="platform_coretemp_0",sensor="temp1"}`
- `node_hwmon_sensor_label` which is a helper time series for temperature sensors that have a name (the Prometheus label called `label`):

  - `{chip="platform_coretemp_0",sensor="temp1",label="core_0"}`

On https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter/issues/631 it is explained that:

> labels are not available for all sensors. If all you sensors have a label, you can do something like this to join them:
>
> ```
> node_hwmon_temp_celsius{...} * ignoring(label) group_left(label) node_hwmon_sensor_label
> ```

But some of my sensors don't have a label. The above PromQL query does not help in that case; `group_left(label)` returns no results in that case.

**Instead, I would like to write a query for the temperatures that has the `label` label present, always, and *defaults* it to `unknown-sensor-name`  if the `label` label is missing.**

How can I do this with PromQL?

Answer (score 4):

I finally found a solution (not sure if it's optimal):

```py
(
    # For all sensors that have a name (label "label"), join them with `node_hwmon_sensor_label` to get that name.
    (node_hwmon_temp_celsius * ignoring(label) group_left(label) node_hwmon_sensor_label)
  or
    # For all sensors that do NOT a name (label "label") in `node_hwmon_sensor_label`, assign them `label="unknown-sensor-name"`.
    # `label_replace()` only adds the new label, it does not remove the old one.
    (label_replace((node_hwmon_temp_celsius unless ignoring(label) node_hwmon_sensor_label), "label", "unknown-sensor-name", "", ".*"))
)
```

How I arrived there:

- Finding all time series that do NOT have the label `label` is essentially the equivalent of an `OUTER JOIN` from SQL; googling that for PromQL I found question [Is there a way to do a "left outer join" like query in PromQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67599290/is-there-a-way-to-do-a-left-outer-join-like-query-in-promql) that explains that this is `unless` in PromQL.
- Now we need to add the constant `label="unknown-sensor-name"`. We can do that with [`label_replace()`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#label_replace), which, perhaps confusingly, only really adds a new label, it does not remove the old one (as described [here](https://medium.com/@texasdave2/replace-and-remove-a-label-in-a-prometheus-query-9500faa302f0)). We can leave the last 2 arguments as `""` since we only add a constant string, so we can match any existing label.
- Finally, we can union-join this with the "if all you sensors have a label" series using `or`.

Done.

---

If desired, we can also join it up with the machine's hostname by adding:

```
* on(instance) group_left(nodename) node_uname_info
```

That is described in https://blog.ruanbekker.com/cheatsheets/prometheus/ or [Relabel instance to hostname in Prometheus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49896956/relabel-instance-to-hostname-in-prometheus).

That way, in Grafana, we can use `{{nodename}} {{chip}} {{label}}` for the Legend of the graph.

---

Example in Grafana (showing `instance` instead of `nodename`):

[image: Grafana showing temperatures with sensor labels]

Comment: I've posted a solution that I believe may be preferable below, although even if you prefer it, this answer still has a lot of value because this is a good technique where the default is not hard-coded (i.e. if not set, try to pull label from some other label in another metric) I believe

Answer (score 3):

Just wrap the recommended query into [label_replace()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#label_replace) function:

```
label_replace(
  node_hwmon_temp_celsius
    * ignoring(label) group_left(label)
  node_hwmon_sensor_label,
  "label",
  "unknown-sensor-name",
  "label",
  ""
)
```

The `label_replace()` searches for missing `label` values and then replaces them with the `label="unknown-sensor-name"`. It doesn't change already existing `label` values, since they do not match the provided empty regular expression in the last argument to `label_replace()`. Prometheus automatically anchors the regexp to the start and the end of the string, e.g. in reality it uses `^$` regexp, which matches only an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the fact that `label_replace` allows you to supply a regex match as a requirement for replacement, and replace only if it matches against an empty string (i.e. no label present):

```
label_replace(
  <your metric>,
  <label>,
  <default value>,
  <label>,
  "^$"
)
```

Or in your case specifically:

```
label_replace(
  <your metric>,
  "label",
  "unknown-sensor-name",
  "label",
  "^$"
)
```

Where `^` is the special character used in Regexes to denote the beginning of a string, and `$` is the same for the end of a string.

Comment: This is a clever way to add a label

Answer (score 0):

Better way to handle this by adding "default" values for missing label.

```
      relabelings
        - sourceLabels:[__meta_xx_name]
          targetLabel: label_name   
        - sourceLabels:[__meta_xx_name]
          targetLabel: label_name
          replacement: "default_value"
          regex: ^$
```

It will also be helpful if panel variables are impacted because of missing this label.